# Network configuration timed out in Ubuntu core-16

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

I am trying to setup Ubuntu core on pi 3 for the first time with the image downloaded from [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/)
.

I got stocked at network configuration. After filling up my network settings, I got

[image: Sample]

I tried to skip it but can't find a way. Any help for a newbie will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear in the "Prerequisites for booting Ubuntu Core", but you need network connectivity in order to register your Ubuntu SSO account in Raspberry PI and later to verify your SSH Key.

Without network connectivity you will not proceed to next screen.

Comment: Network on WiFi and LAN is connected. Looks like bug to me. May be I start afresh.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is an issue with the wifi chipset on the Pi3: [RPi 3 - Very poor wifi performance](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=138312). Some issue with the power management as well as a possible compatibility issue with certain router chipset. I ended up hardwiring the Pi (which was not ideal).